# remove double quote from array value while saving - php

Tags: php, laravel-5, permissions, cartalyst-sentinel

I have an array like below which comes from form:

```
array:4 [▼
  "login-history.view" => "true"
  "login-history.create" => "true"
  "login-history.edit" => "true"
  "login-history.delete" => "true"
]
```

I want to store it in database like this:

```
{
"login-history.view":true, //without double qoute in value true and false.
"login-history.create":true,
"login-history.edit":true,
"login-history.delete":true
}
```

But, when I saved it, it always saves like below:

```
{
"login-history.view":"true", //I want to remove double quote around true and false for every value 
"login-history.create":"true",
"login-history.edit":"true",
"login-history.delete":"true"
}
```

I want to save the record without double qoute around `value(true and false)`. I currently simply saving the values as in eloquent value saving

```
$permissions = $request->get('permissions');
$role = Sentinel::findRoleBySlug($slug); //slug is role slug ex. admin, manager, user
$role->permissions = $permissions;
$role->save()
```

How can I achieve it?

**Update**

I am using Laravel 5.4 and mysql database, Cartalyst Sentinel Package for ACL

Comment: What database are you using? Post more code around the place where you do the saving.

Comment: `array_walk($myArray, function (&$value) { $value === 'true' ? true : false; } );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a brute force approach to the problem as defined above

```
foreach($myArray as $key=>$value){
    $myArray[$key] = $value==='true' ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: great it works. Can you please explain why `$myArray[$key] = $value`? can't we simply use `$value===`

Comment: @vijayrana at the very least, you'd have to do this in the foreach: `$myArray[$key] = $value==='true;`.

Comment: it doesn't make sense @Terminus, what does `at the very least` mean? can you please explain a bit

Comment: @vijayrana Sorry for the confjusion. In this case, it means you don't need the `? true : false` part. You don't need it because `$value === 'true'` already give you true or false.

Comment: you can skip true : false part I added this just to make it more self explanatory if minimalism is what you looking for one liner should suffice